# Why does navigator.credentials.get request take a long time?

Tags: credentials, webauthn

It takes about 20-25 seconds for navigator.credentials.get to come back. Is there to make this faster?

Comment: Since it triggers user interaction are you not just encountering a default timeout in this case? Can you provide a bit more information about what your expectations are?